# checking of field in a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Let's say I have the following schema

```
 var userSchema = new Schema({
    name : String
  });

  var User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

**EDIT**: If an user trying to update field, that does not exists, I need throw exception. My question is how can I check that an updating field does not exists in the updating document. Here is a little example what I need:

```
  app.post('/user/update/:id', function (req, res) {
     var field = req.param('field'),
          value = req.param('value'),
          id = req.param('id');

     User.findOne({_id: id},function(err, user){
        if(err) throw err;

        if (user) {

          user[field] = value;          // Here is I need to check that field is exists
                                        // in user schema. If does't I have to throw 
                                        // an execption.

          user.save(function (err){
             return res.send(200);
          });
        }            
     })
  });
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is

Comment: because he didn't ask a question, he just stated what he did

Comment: I've added more information about my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `$exists` to the query parameter of update(). This will allow you to only update documents if a certain field exists (or not).

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I need thow an expention if does't extsts.

Comment: @Erik - right, if it doesn't exist, then the you can check the result of the update with `$exists` to see that nupdated = 0 (if you are using safe mode), and then throw an exception there.

Answer (score 0):

From the Mongoose v3.1.2 guide:

> The strict option, (enabled by default), ensures that values added to our model instance that were not specified in our schema do not get saved to the db. NOTE: do not set to false unless you have good reason.
>
> The strict option may also be set to "throw" which will cause errors to be produced instead of ignoring the bad data.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict

Answer (score 0):

```
var CollectionSchema = new Schema({name: 'string'}, {strict: 'throw'});

Collection.findById(id)
  .exec(function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {// handle error};

    // Try to update not existing field
    doc['im not exists'] = 'some';
    doc.save(function (err) {
      if (err) {
         // There is no an errors
      }

      return res.json(200, 'OK');
    });

  });
```

In the expample above I don't get an error when I do update a not existing field.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the `field` exists in the `schema` by using `.schema.path()`. In your specific use case you can do the following:

```
app.post('/user/update/:id', function (req, res) {
 var field = req.param('field'),
      value = req.param('value'),
      id = req.param('id');

  User.findOne({_id: id},function(err, user){
    if(err) throw err;

    if (user) {

      if(User.schema.path(field)) {
        user[field] = value;
      } else {
        throw new Error('Field [' + field + '] does not exists.');
      }

      user.save(function (err){
        return res.send(200);
      });
    }            
  });
});
```